# Apply tfidf to a pandas column of word tokens

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I now have a df with a list of tokenized words,I want to create an additional column with tfidf scores of each token in that column(corpus being all tokens in that column, and tf calculated with the group of tokens in each row).

Thanks[image]

Comment: Please provide examples of your `df`

Comment: Please see the edited post, I've uploaded a screenshot of the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def dummy(tokens):
    return tokens

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=dummy, preprocessor=dummy)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Processed'].values)
features = pd.DataFrame(X.todense(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```